# Multiple copies of react/ multiple node_modules folders

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, node-modules

I have an ASP.NET Core React project in Visual Studio 2022. I'm attempting to use React, React-Router-Dom, and Bootstrap. I've done something wrong installing these via NPM as my application won't load and I get a 'multiple copies of react' error in the console. There are two node-modules folders, one at root and the other inside my ClientApp folder, which seems incorrect to me. I also see that when importing react and react-bootstrap in one of my components, they seem to be coming from different places.

Import React:
[This seems normal - imported from my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vjmT.png)

Import Bootstrap:
[Why is this coming from user appdata?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzeft.png)

I've deleted the node_modules folder at the project root, cleared NPM cache and reinstalled, but this didn't seem to help.

How do I eliminate the duplicate node_modules folders?
And how do I direct my imports to that folder?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could remove all the  node_modules folder at the project root and the node_modules folder inside the ClientApp folder.

Then check your project's json to make sure the package.json's dependencies are listed correctly in your package.json file. Make sure that you're not listing any duplicate dependencies.

Then re-build the project and the project will install the dependencies by default and check if the node_modules folder well now.